# Python quickbooks categories

Tags: python, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to create a QuickBooks Category using `python-quickbooks` package.

However, I cannot seem to find this object in the package. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [the fo_qbo repo](https://github.com/finoptimal/fo_qbo). You would use `qbs.create("Account", {your_category_blob})`.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation about Category](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/item#create-a-category) it looks like you need to use [Item entity](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks/blob/master/quickbooks/objects/item.py) with specific payload, like:

```json
{
  "SubItem": true, 
  "Type": "Category", 
  "Name": "Cedar", 
  "ParentRef": {
    "name": "Trees", 
    "value": "29"
  }
}
```

See more details on [this page](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/item#create-a-category).